# Just a little absoluteness might be cheaper?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

Absoluteness is a wonderful thing, but expensive consistency-strength wise. My question is, when can we get large amounts of absoluteness in specific situations for much cheaper?

Specifically, fix a definable forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ - it is reasonable to ask how hard it would be to find a model where, say, $\Pi^1_3$ statements aren't changed by forcing with $\mathbb{P}$. For example, take $\mathbb{P}$ to be Cohen forcing. Then $L$ is certainly not such a model, but any forcing extension of $L$ by $\mathbb{P}$ is. On the other hand, there are certainly definable forcing notions such that the statement "Forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ doesn't change the truth value of $\Pi^1_3$ sentences" requires consistency strength beyond ZFC.

My question is when we can make "local absoluteness assumptions" without additional consistency strength. For a specific instance of this question:

> Are there reasonable hypotheses on definable forcings $\mathbb{P}$ which imply that the statement $$\text{$PA(\mathbb{P})$ = "Projective sentences are absolute under forcing with $\mathbb{P}$"}$$ has no additional consistency strength?

I would ask for sufficient *and necessary* conditions, but I think that's demanding far too much.

---

*I've added the "descriptive set theory" tag because I think it may be relevant; feel free to delete if you think that's bonkers.*

Comment: Sy and I have a cute result along these lines in our joint paper. Nice question! The Tomek-Haim book should have some additional examples (at low levels), with a more recent paper by Joan and Hugh showing that there are no higher level versions of some of these results.

Comment: Is the paper by you and Sy the one on BPFA? If so, could you email it to me? I can't find a copy online (JSTOR says it's not archived for some reason).

Comment: Noah, it should be downloadable from my blog. (Recent issues of the JSL are first available through Project Euclid, with subscription, and added to JSTOR a few years later.)

Comment: I don't understand your claim that after forcing by $\mathbb{P}$ over $L$, we get a model where $\Pi^1_3$ statements aren't changed by (further) forcing with $\mathbb{P}$. This doesn't seem to be true for all $\mathbb{P}$. One can build wild counterexamples by defining $\mathbb{P}$ by "if $V=L$, then $\mathbb{P}$ is like this simple thing, and otherwise it is like this other wild thing". You are assuming that the forcing relation for forcing $\Pi^1_3$ statements is the same in $V$ as it is in $V^{\mathbb{P}}$, or what?

Comment: Also, even if $\mathbb{P}$ was literally the same poset in $L$ and the extension by $L$ of $\mathbb{P}$, if it wasn't homogeneous, then one can make the poset do totally different things under different conditions.

Comment: Of course you're right, I left out a clause - $\mathbb{P}$ was specifically meant to be Cohen forcing in that example.

Comment: By a result of Brendle, $\Sigma_4^1$-Amoeba absoluteness implies that $\aleph_1$ is inaccessible in $L$: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9209206v1.pdf So a necessary condition for a property that implies $PA(\mathbb{P})$ is that it doesn't hold for Amoeba forcing.

Comment: see also the master thesis of Peter Holy: [Absoluteness Results in Set Theory](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/pholy/dip.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Some partial results:

- Bagaria showed that $\Sigma^1_3$-absoluteness for c.c.c. forcings is equiconsistent with ZFC, in fact a consequence of $MA+\neg CH$: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2275537?loginSuccess=true&seq=5#page_scan_tab_contents, Theorem 6.
- On the other hand, Bagaria and Friedman showed that $\Sigma^1_4$-absoluteness for c.c.c. forcings is equiconsistent with a weakly compact: http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~sdf/papers/bagfried.pdf, Theorem 7.

Since c.c.c. is about as nice as one usually gets, this paints a pessimistic picture of getting full projective absoluteness, with no additional consistency assumptions, for a reasonable class of forcing notions; but maybe we can still get lucky.

Comment: A weird aside: Bagaria and Friedman also show that $\Sigma^1_3$-absoluteness for *proper* forcings implies that either $\omega_1$ is Mahlo in $L$ or $\omega_2$ is inaccessible in $L$.